# How do I fix these errors in react native?

Tags: reactjs, npm

> ```
>                     === npm audit security report ===                        
>
>
>                                Manual Review                                  
>            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             
>
>         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           
>
>
> Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service                          
>
> Package         braces                                                        
>
> Patched in      >=2.3.1                                                       
>
> Dependency of   8c984aa2242a52d5bd2134b7630f7689f54957761213aefb60250c47331…  
>
> Path            8c984aa2242a52d5bd2134b7630f7689f54957761213aefb60250c47331…  
>                 > @react-native-community/cli > metro > jest-haste-map >      
>                 micromatch > braces                                           
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/786                              
>
>
>
> Low             Denial of Service                                             
>
> Package         mem                                                           
>
> Patched in      >=4.0.0                                                       
>
> Dependency of   8c984aa2242a52d5bd2134b7630f7689f54957761213aefb60250c47331…  
>
> Path            8c984aa2242a52d5bd2134b7630f7689f54957761213aefb60250c47331…  
>                 > @react-native-community/cli > metro > yargs > os-locale >   
>              mem                                                           
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084                             
>
>
> Low             Denial of Service                                             
>
> Package         mem                                                           
>
> Patched in      >=4.0.0                                                       
>
> Dependency of   8c984aa2242a52d5bd2134b7630f7689f54957761213aefb60250c47331…  
>
> Path            8c984aa2242a52d5bd2134b7630f7689f54957761213aefb60250c47331…  
>                 > @react-native-community/cli > metro-config > metro > yargs  
>                 > os-locale > mem                                             
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084                             
>
>
> Low             Denial of Service                                             
>
> Package         mem                                                           
>
> Patched in      >=4.0.0                                                       
>
> Dependency of   8c984aa2242a52d5bd2134b7630f7689f54957761213aefb60250c47331…  
>
> Path            8c984aa2242a52d5bd2134b7630f7689f54957761213aefb60250c47331…  
>                 > yargs > os-locale > mem                                     
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084                             
>
> found 14 low severity vulnerabilities in 922851 scanned packages
> 14 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
> ```